# Omitting an 'optional' step in gaussian-elimination causes different result

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to invert a matrix using the gaussian-elimination method

This is my start matrix

```
+---------+--------+
| 1 -2 -2 | 1 0 0  |
| -2 1 -2 | 0 1 0  |
| -2 -2 1 | 0 0 1  |
+---------+--------+
```

> 1. Using the top left `1` as pivot I can eliminate the first column, the result is

```
+---------+--------+
| 1 -2 -2 | 1 0 0  |
| 0 -3 -6 | 2 1 0  |
| 0 -6 -3 | 2 0 1  |
+---------+--------+
```

> 2. Selecting the middle `-3` as pivot, I eliminate the second column, the result is

```
+---------+--------+
| -3 0 -6 |  1 2 0 |
| 0 -3 -6 | 2 1 0  |
| 0 0 -9  | 2 2 -1 |
+---------+--------+
```

> 3. And finally selecting the bottom right `-9`as pivot, I eliminate the last column, the result is

```
+--------+----------+
| 9 0 0  |  1 -2 -2 |
| 0 -9 0 | -2 1 -2  |
| 0 0 -9 | 2 2 -1   |
+--------+----------+
```

> 4. Simplifying gives

```
+-------+---------------+
| 1 0 0 | 1/9 -2/9 -2/9 |
| 0 1 0 | 2/9 -1/9 2/9  |
| 0 0 1 | -2/9 -2/9 1/9 |
+-------+---------------+
```

But when checking the answer [online](http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/inverse-of-matrix-calculator/?i=%5B%5B1%2C-2%2C-2%5D%2C%5B-2%2C1%2C-2%5D%2C%5B-2%2C-2%2C1%5D%5D&steps=on), I found out my result is wrong, it should be

```
+-------+---------------+
| 1 0 0 | 1/9 -2/9 -2/9 |
| 0 1 0 | -2/9 1/9 -2/9 |
| 0 0 1 | -2/9 -2/9 1/9 |
+-------+---------------+
```

(difference on the middle row, the numbers on the second row on the right side should be multiplied by -1)

I checked on different sites and they all showed me to divide row 2 by -3 after step 1.

For example on another site
[image]

What I do not understand is why they divide the second row by -3. Isn't this an optional step? Shouldn't it make no difference when not dividing by -3 or are multiple answers possible?

Comment: You made a sign error in the second row in step 3. That’s why it doesn’t match the correct answer.

Comment: @peterwhy It shouldn't be wrong, what does look wrong?

Comment: @Denny sorry, I didn't notice the extra sign flip, so that particular step 2 is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After step 3 before step 4, the result should be

$$\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{-3&0&-6&1&2&0\\
0&-3&-6&2&1&0\\
0&0&-9&2&2&-1}
&\xrightarrow{R_1\to -3R_1+2R_3}
\pmatrix{9&0&0&1&-2&-2\\
0&-3&-6&2&1&0\\
0&0&-9&2&2&-1}\\
&\xrightarrow{R_2\to3R_2-2R_3}
\pmatrix{9&0&0&1&-2&-2\\
0&-9&0&2&-1&2\\
0&0&-9&2&2&-1}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why is it `3*row2 - 2*row3`? I used `2*row3 - 3*row2` which yields the same result for `-9` and `-6`

Comment: $2R_3-3R_2$ is just the negative, which is $$\pmatrix{0&\color{red}9&0&-2&1&-2}.$$

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong now, it was just a stupid calculation error I made, `(2*0)-(3*-3)` is `9` but somehow I ended up with `-9`.